# Projection of 2D disque into 3D sphere in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently working on an astrophysics project. The goal is to emulate stellar spots onto a picture of a simulation of the surface of a K Dwarf.

I have a picture (x,y) with the intensity on the z-axis.

[image: K Dwarf simulation]

[image: K Dwarf 3D intensity projection]

My goal is to project a disc representing a spot onto the surface taking into account the 3D form of the simulation (intensity) for the moment I can project a dark disc to simulate the transit of a planet but I can't project a 2D disc on the 3D surface.

My 2D mask is like this:

```
_masks = []
_intens = []
y,x = np.ogrid[-a:n-a, -b:n-b]
mask = x*x + y*y <= r*r
star[mask] = 0
_intens.append(np.sum(star[star>0])/intensite_max)
_masks.append(mask)
```

with `a` and `b` the projected center position, `n` is the size of the star (in pixel).

My actual projection is like this:

[image: K Dwarf with dark mask projected]

But, as you see, the mask doesn't take into account the 3D surface of the star.

How could I project a 2D disc onto a 3D object? (in python)

Comment: Plot a surface with the masked x and y values and z taken from the original surface. Make the color uniform black instead of z-based

Comment: Thanks @MadPhysicist but what I'm looking for is a deformation of a circle in 2D with the z depth like x cos(theta) + y sin(theta)